# Installing tesseract ocr in mac OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, tesseract

I'm having trouble installing tesseract in mac OS.I installed tesseract using

```
brew install tesseract
```

When I try to use tesseract command,I get this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am kinda stuck here actually and I have no idea what to do

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error? I found [a possible fix here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3806), [another here](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-mozjpeg/issues/23#issuecomment-355880372), the [same question on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59014528/735926) and a [similar one there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22631026/735926). Please try the fixes and edit your question to add details re what you’ve tried and what doesn’t work. Also, please copy/paste the error message instead of posting a screenshot. Thanks!